# Doctrine batch inserting uses 2GB of Ram

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, batch-insert

I am trying to insert approximately 200k of records with Symfony2 and  Doctrine via Doctrine Fixtures Bundle. I am using flush and clear but at the end script uses 1.8 GB of RAM.

This is the class that loads SmartMeter entities into database:

```
<?php

namespace HTEC\SmartMeteringAPIBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;

use HTEC\SmartMeteringAPIBundle\Entity\SmartMeter;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LoadSmartMeterData extends AbstractFixture implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface, OrderedFixtureInterface
{

    static $NUMBER_OF_SMART_METERS = 0;
    static $MAX_NUM_OF_SM_PER_CONC = 500;

     /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;


    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 10; // the order in which fixtures will be loaded
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {

        $numberOfUsers = LoadUserData::$NUMBER_OF_USERS;
        $numberOfConcentrators = LoadConcentratorData::$NUMBER_OF_CONCENTRATORS;
        $numberOfTariffs = LoadTariffData::$NUMBER_OF_TARIFFS;

        $numberOfSmartMetersPerConcentrator = 0;

        $smartMeter = null;
        $concentrator = null;
        $user = null;
        $tariff = null;

        $feeders = array();
        $numberOfFeeders = 0;
        $feedersRandomKey = array();

        $isIpAddressDynamic = false;

        $numberOfTransformerFeeders = 0;

        $smartMeterType = 0;
        $smartMeterProtocol = 0;
        $modemType = 0;

        $numberOfSmartMeters = 0;


        echo "\n\nCreating Smart Meters. This could take a couple of minutes and could take approximately 2 GB of RAM \n\n...";

        $startTime = time();

        $smartMeterCount = 0;

        $lastChunkNumber = 0;
        $currentChunkNumber = 0;

        $lastSmartMeterNumber = 0;
        $smartMetersClearedCurrently = 0;

        $concentratorSmartMeters = null;

        for($i = 0; $i < LoadConcentratorData::$NUMBER_OF_CONCENTRATORS; $i++)
        {

            $concentrator = $manager->getRepository('SMAPIBundle:Concentrator')->find($i+1);

            $numberOfSmartMetersPerConcentrator = rand(1, self::$MAX_NUM_OF_SM_PER_CONC);

            $numberOfSmartMeters += $numberOfSmartMetersPerConcentrator;

            for($c = 0; $c < $numberOfSmartMetersPerConcentrator; $c++)
            {
                $smartMeter = new SmartMeter();
                $smartMeter->setSerialNumber(++$smartMeterCount);
                $smartMeter->setConcentrator($concentrator);

                $smartMeterType = rand(1,3);

                switch($smartMeterType)
                {
                    case 1:
                        $smartMeter->setType('DIRECT');
                    break;

                    case 2:
                        $smartMeter->setType('HALF');
                    break;

                    case 3:
                        $smartMeter->setType('INDIRECT');
                    break;
                }

                $user = $manager->getRepository('SMAPIBundle:User')->find(rand(1, $numberOfUsers));
                $smartMeter->setCreatedBy($user);

                $numberOfTransformerFeeders = $concentrator->getTransformerFeeders()->count();
                $feeders = $concentrator->getTransformerFeeders()->toArray();

                if($numberOfTransformerFeeders > 0)
                {

                    $feedersRandomKey = array_rand($feeders, 1);

                    if(isset($feeders[$feedersRandomKey]))
                    {
                        $smartMeter->setFeeder($feeders[$feedersRandomKey]);
                    }
                }

                $smartMeter->setStatus(rand(0,2));


                $tariff = $manager->getRepository('SMAPIBundle:Tariff')->find(rand(1, $numberOfTariffs));
                $smartMeter->setTariff($tariff);

                $smartMeterProtocol = rand(1,3);

                switch($smartMeterProtocol)
                {
                    case 1:
                        $smartMeter->setProtocol('DLMS');
                    break;

                    case 2:
                        $smartMeter->setProtocol('EURIDIS');
                    break;

                    case 3:
                        $smartMeter->setProtocol('IEC');
                    break;
                }


                $smartMeter->setModemSerialNumber(rand(1, 9000000000));

                $smartMeter->setManufacture('MAN: ' . ($i + $c));

                $modemType = rand(1,2);

                if($modemType === 1)
                {
                    $smartMeter->setModemType('PLC');
                    $smartMeter->setModemIndex(rand(1, 512));
                }
                else
                {

                    $smartMeter->setModemType('GPRS');
                    $isIpAddressDynamic = rand(0,1);

                    if($isIpAddressDynamic === 1)
                    {
                        $smartMeter->setModemIpAddress(rand(1000000, 2000000));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $smartMeter->setModemPhoneNumber($this->getRandomIpAddressV4());
                    }
                }


                if(rand(0,1) === 1)
                {
                    $smartMeter->setModemRepeaterNumber(rand(10000000, 90000000));
                }

                $manager->persist($smartMeter);

            } // end of FOR numberOfSmartMetersPerConcentrator

            // flush smart meters
            $manager->flush();
            $manager->clear();

            $currentChunkNumber = ceil($smartMeterCount / 5000);

            if($smartMeterCount > 5000 && $currentChunkNumber > $lastChunkNumber)
            {
                $lastChunkNumber = $currentChunkNumber;



                if($lastSmartMeterNumber > 0)
                {
                    $smartMetersClearedCurrently = $smartMeterCount - $lastSmartMeterNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    $smartMetersClearedCurrently = $smartMeterCount;
                }


                echo "\n\nFlushing and clearing " . number_format($smartMetersClearedCurrently, 0, ',', '.') . " Smart Meters.\nTotal memory used after flush and clear: " . number_format(((memory_get_usage(true) / 1024) / 1024), 2, ',', '.') . " Megabytes\n\n...";

                $lastSmartMeterNumber = $smartMeterCount;
            }
        }// end for NUMBER_OF_CONCENTRATORS

        $manager->flush();
        $manager->clear();

        unset($concentrator);
        unset($smartMeter);
        unset($tariff);

        echo "\n\n-------------------------------------------\n\n";
        echo "\n\nTotal memory used after final flush and clear of Smart Meters: " . number_format(((memory_get_usage(true) / 1024) / 1024), 2, ',', '.') . " Megabytes\n\n...";

        echo "\n\nCreating Smart Meters complete. Created " . number_format($numberOfSmartMeters, 0, ',', '.') . " Smart Meters.\n\n";

        $durationSeconds = (time() - $startTime);
        $durationMinutes = $durationSeconds / 60;

        $secondsRemainder = $durationSeconds % 60;

        echo "\n\nTotal duration time: " . ceil($durationMinutes) . " minutes and " . $secondsRemainder . " seconds.\n\n\n";

        self::$NUMBER_OF_SMART_METERS = $numberOfSmartMeters;

    }

    public function getRandomIpAddressV4()
    {
        return rand(1, 255) . '.' . rand(0, 255) . '.' . rand(0, 255) . '.' . rand(0, 255);
    }
}
```

On approximately 5000 records I am calling flush and clear but it seams that no memory is released.

Are there recommendations about how to prevent Doctrine from using too much RAM during batch tasks?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well obviously why is it using so much memory why the memory is not released.

Comment: The question is pretty clear, doctrine is using an outstanding amount of memory and the question is how to prevent it. It is a common pitfall in batch tasks.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. I don't see the difficulty of putting the actual question explicitly in the inquiry right away. You want something from us and saying "the question is obvious" is as unhelpful as stating "the code is obviously documenting itself". No harm in trying to supply as much help as possible to your helpers by trying to get as close to a perfect question as possible. Again, thanks for listening and editing your question. I really hope you manage to solve it. Have a good one. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a command, try running it with the option `--no-debug`. Or, you can disable the logger by calling `$manager->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);` at the beginning of your `load`function.

Either way disabling the logger saves quite a lot of memory during Doctrine batch tasks.

Comment: Thanks man. When I just passed --no-debug option the memory consumption stayed the same (45,75 MiB) through all ~200k inserts which is a drastic change from (1.8 GiB ) used before. Why is it that without the  --no-debug option script consumes so much memory?

Comment: The thing is that if the doctrine logger is active, it stores every call in memory to log it. This is not a problem in normal request-response operations, but it is in batch inserts. In symfony, the doctrine logging config option is set to `logging:              "%kernel.debug%"` as default. So, if you are running your commands in a mode with debug mode on (dev, test), it will enable logging and will suck all the RAM.